# In the xamarin forms shell, how do I not display the bottom tab when I go to the next page

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

In this example,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbxzV.png)
click the item item to jump to the detail page,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmW8N.png)
but I don't want to display the bottom tab on the total page. I used [shell. Current. Navigation. Pushmodal async], but the result is that it doesn't realize the top navigation bar. Now I want to ask how to jump to display the top navigation bar without displaying the bottom tab

some code:

```
<FlyoutItem Route="animals"
            FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
    <Tab Title="Domestic"
         Route="domestic"
         Icon="paw.png">
        <ShellContent Route="cats"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Cats"
                      Icon="cat.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:CatsPage}" />
        <ShellContent Route="dogs"
                      Style="{StaticResource DomesticShell}"
                      Title="Dogs"
                      Icon="dog.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:DogsPage}" />
    </Tab>
    <ShellContent Route="monkeys"
                  Style="{StaticResource MonkeysShell}"
                  Title="Monkeys"
                  Icon="monkey.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MonkeysPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="elephants"
                  Style="{StaticResource ElephantsShell}"
                  Title="Elephants"
                  Icon="elephant.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:ElephantsPage}" />
    <ShellContent Route="bears"
                  Style="{StaticResource BearsShell}"
                  Title="Bears"
                  Icon="bear.png"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:BearsPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

and

```
 await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//animals/monkeys/monkeydetails?name={monkeyName}");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I want to ask how to jump to display the top navigation bar
> without displaying the bottom tab

The simplest method is to add following code for your detail page:

```
  Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"
```

The whole sample code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Xaminals.Views.ElephantDetailPage"

              Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"

             Title="Elephant Details">
    <ScrollView>
        <StackLayout Margin="20">
            <!--other code-->
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```